# Npm can't install the posix

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to install the posix but I can't.I am getting this errors:

http://prntscr.com/2bnhwv

How can I resolve it ?

Comment: "Install the posix"? Do you even know what POSIX is?

Comment: @H2CO3 no,I want to remove concurrent users limit from nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your python is 2.4.3 you need to update it. This task is different for each linux distribution.

posix has some C++ source code, that will be built by node-gyp, and node-gyp do require python 2.5 or 2.6 or 2.7 but not 3.x

Read your error message for more details.

---

open terminal, then copy paste these commands

```
sudo wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
sudo wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-5*.rpm epel-release-5*.rpm
sudo yum install python26
```

I donot use centos5 now, i do not know if it work or not.

Comment: hmm,do u know how can I update the python ?

Comment: I am using Centos 5.11

Comment: I tried,it was successfully complete but When I check the ptyhon version it's still says to me you have 2.4.3

Comment: sudo yum remove python, then sudo yum install python, remove '26'

Comment: I removed python,now I am getting no such file or directory error.

Comment: now, sudo yum install python :)

Comment: here is http://prntscr.com/2boj1r

Comment: omg! big broblem now! let me try with my virtual centos

Comment: I can reinstall in centos6, I think that remove make an accident on centos5. Do you have any restore or backup?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GBHhzEHv